# Not getting excel data

Tags: c#, .net, excel, filestream

I need to format excel data and then add it to database.
I have file in xls format and direct importing it to database is returning date/time column in wrong format. After converting into xlsx its format is in correct format. But when i convert xls to xlsx from my code . It is returning null in stream. Any idea? 
Here is my code

```
var path = String.Format("{0}\\attendance", System.Environment.CurrentDirectory);

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        excelApp.Visible = false;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook eWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(path+".xls", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

        eWorkbook.SaveAs(path+".xlsx", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

        eWorkbook.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

        FileStream stream = File.Open(path+".xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
      //  stream.Close();

        excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
        DataSet _ds = excelReader.AsDataSet();
```

Comment: You are not showing any exception handling.  Are you sure no exceptions are being thrown? `It is returning null in stream` does this mean you stepped through in a debugger, and File.Open(...) returned null?  Is the file actually present in the file system after the call to SaveAs()?

Comment: This is the exception in debugging details but not throwing :
System.IO.Stream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException.....

Yes i got the file in my folder with xlsx type.

Comment: `This is the exception in debugging details but not throwing` that is only because FileStream does not provide an implementation for ReadTimeout, but the debugger tries to get the value of that property for visualization.  It does not affect your code.  You may need to close excelApp.  It might still hold a lock on the .xlsx file.